# Why doesn't & show up in a Windows Forms Label?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Consider:

```
Label label = new Label();

label.Text = "&";
```

But... I can't see the **&**, after I run the program.

[image: Code]

How do I show that character in a label?

I want to show only the character. &

Comment: didn't you get compile error for not closing quotation properly?

Comment: See the screenshot, they did so correctly.

Answer (score 20):

That's because `&` in labels, buttons and menus is prefixed to access key characters, i.e. those characters you can press with <kbd>Alt</kbd> to give focus to a control directly.

```
label1.UseMnemonic = false;
```

will get rid of that behaviour.

From the documentation of [`UseMnemonic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx):

> **true** if the label doesn't display the ampersand character and underlines the character after the ampersand in its displayed text and treats the underlined character as an access key; otherwise, **false** if the ampersand character is displayed in the text of the control. The default is **true**.

If you need to display `&` *and* the access key behaviour, then you need to escape the `&` as `&&`, as several other answers mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "&&";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`&` is used as a Localizable resource in Windows Forms. And it is also used to specify shortcuts. So you need to escape it:

```
this.label1.Text = "&&";
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the reason *and* a solution.